# D3. Axes. What is the correct way to draw an axis for an ordinal scale

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart that renders a histogram.

[image]

Drawn vertically, the horizontal x-axis is in units of "items in a bin". My problem is the x-axis. I am unclear on how to configure `d3.svg.axis()` to draw the axis with units at the bottom of the chart. Things are a bit complicated by the fact that I flip the orientation of the bins around the y-axis to indicate they contain negative values (flipped left) or positive values (flipped right).

### UPDATE

Here is the relevant code.

An object that hosts my histogram. I have removed non-relevant code. 
self.datasource is an array of objects of the form { id: name, score: score_value }

```
scarpa.ConnectivityScoreHistogram = function (dataset) {

    var self = this;

    this.histogramDataSource = d3.layout.histogram()
        .value (function(d) { return d.score; })
        .bins(binThresholds)
    (self.datasource);

    this.extent = d3.extent(this.histogramDataSource, histogramXDomainMapper);

    // Set domain for x and y scales. Range is set in renderer
    this.xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(this.extent);

    this.yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(this.histogramDataSource.map(histogramYDomainMapper));

};  

function histogramXDomainMapper(d) {
    return doPertCount(d);
}

function doPertCount(d) {
    return (d.x < 0) ? -(d.y) : d.y;
}

function histogramYDomainMapper(d) {
    return d.x.toString();
}
```

At data join time I fill out the remainder of the scales, join data, and render histogram and axis. Here I just show the axis rendering.

```
histogram.yScale.rangeBands([bbox.height, 0], .125);

// scale range
histogram.xScale.range([0, histogram.scaleFactor * bbox.width]);

// axis
histogram.xAxis = d3.svg.axis();
histogram.xAxis.scale(histogram.xScale);
histogram.xAxis.orient("bottom");
histogram.xAxis.ticks(10);

// SVG element hierarchy buildout

// histogram group
histogramGroup = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", label)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + bbox.x + "," + bbox.y + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + bbox.height + ")")
    .call(histogram.xAxis);
```

The axis does **not** appear on screen. But the SVG elements are added to the DOM hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: please add your code. it is quite difficult to help you without it.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3259783) of an ordinal axis. Is your question how to do this technically or what would be the best approach to draw it in your case?